# Error al realizar una tabla con Ajax y JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de visualizar unos datos que contiene el `archivo.json` en una tabla mediante JavaScript y Ajax usando el evento `addEventListener` en un botón.

He revisado mi código junto con la consola de JavaScript, pero no me muestra ningún error en ninguna línea.

Lo malo es que al momento de presionar el botón no me realiza ninguna acción ni me muestra nada la consola que deba corregir.

Código JavaScript y Ajax:

```html
<button id="boton">Ver funcionalidades</button>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", loadDoc);

function loadDoc() {
    var myObj, xmlhttp, x, txt;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
            txt += "<table border='2'>"
    
            for (x in myObj) {
              txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].Funcionalidad + "</td><td>"  +
               myObj[x].Detalles  + "</td></tr>"
            }
    
            txt += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    };
    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "archivo.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué respuesta te da la petición?

Answer (score 1):

**El problema es que estás usando `this`**

Es mejor evitar el uso de `this`, pues a la larga nos puede traer grandes problemas, como que `this` es tomado como `window`

```js
console.log(this === window);
console.log(globalThis === window);
```

---

No es necesario, pero considerado una buena práctica **abrir XHR antes de cualquier otra operación**

Por lo que tendrías

```
...
xhr.open("GET", "archivo.json");
... // onreadystatechange
```

Entonces resultaría

```
document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch("archivo.json").then(r => {
        r.json().then(response => {
            let txt = "";
            txt += "<table border='2'>";
            for (x in response) {
              txt += "<tr><td>" + response[x].Funcionalidad + "</td><td>"  +
               response[x].Detalles  + "</td></tr>"
            }
    
            txt += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        });
    });
});
```

**Notas**

- Prefiero usar [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch), pues es más rápido y legible de XHR
- Para hacer el código más legible, puedes definir la función primero y después añadir el `eventListener`
- El tercer parámetro de XHR (`"GET", "file", true`) está deprecado, si se usa causará un *warning* en la consola
- Es una buena práctica definir el tipo de valor que tendrá una variable (`var myVar = ""`) antes de reasignarla
- Prefiero `let` a `var`, pues nos da alcance de bloque

---

Si aún prefieres usar XHR, puedes cambiar la posición de `xhr.open()` y poner la función en el `eventListener`

```
document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "archivo.json");
    
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            let txt = "";
            let myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
            txt += "<table border='2'>"
    
            for(let x in myObj) {
              txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].Funcionalidad + "</td><td>"  +
               myObj[x].Detalles  + "</td></tr>"
            }
    
            txt += "</table>"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    });
    
    xmlhttp.send();
});
```

Comment: Me parece genial que sugieras el uso de `fetch()`, pero hay dos cosas que no entiendo: 1. No creo que haya diferencia en incluir una función anónima en el evento respecto a llamar a otra específica. 2. Hablas de evitar el uso de `this` y, sin embargo, tienes `this.readyState` en lugar de `xmlhttp.readyState`, usando `this` dentro de una función flecha, nada recomendable a menos que sepas realmente lo que estás haciendo; en este caso, tengo la impresión de que `this` hará referencia al evento y no a la petición.

Comment: @Triby no me di cuenta del uso de `this` en dicha parte, fue un error al traspasar el código. Gracias por los comentarios

Comment: amigo gracias por responder, probe con tu primer codigo por que me parecieron buenas acotaciones pero al momento de probarlo me da error y me dice Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: myObj is not defined y sigue sin realizar alguna accion

Comment: @BenjaVicos Solucionado, fue un error de tipografía, había que cambiar `myObj` por `response`, pues es el JSON que nos da `fetch`